# How write query to select columns in one record?

Tags: sql

I have query

```
SELECT
    pp.id,
    pp.user_id,
    CONCAT(pp.last_name, ' ', pp.first_name) AS NAME,
    pp.pm_part_inst_id,
    pp.signature_authority_id,
    pp.max_days,
    (SELECT SUM(HOUR) FROM timecard_day WHERE timecard_day.timecard_id = t.id AND t.status = 1) AS requested_days,
    (SELECT SUM(HOUR) FROM timecard_day WHERE timecard_day.timecard_id = t.id AND t.status = 2) AS approved_days
FROM
    pm_participant pp

JOIN timecard t ON
    t.user_id = pp.user_id
```

Now result is:

```
id  user_id NAME        pm_part_inst_id signature_authority_id  max_days    requested_days  approved_days   
4   8       test test   1               0                       500         NULL            1   
4   8       test test   1               0                       500         0.5             NULL
```

Should be:

```
id  user_id NAME        pm_part_inst_id signature_authority_id  max_days    requested_days  approved_days   
4   8       test test   1               0                       500         0.5             1
```

How i can do that?
Thank you for help!

Comment: `GROUP BY` and `MAX` would do the job

Comment: Presumably, participant has one row and TimeCard has two rows; the resultset will thus have two rows

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Conditionally aggregate the result of joining it all together:

```
SELECT
    pp.id,
    pp.user_id,
    CONCAT(pp.last_name, ' ', pp.first_name) AS NAME,
    pp.pm_part_inst_id,
    pp.signature_authority_id,
    pp.max_days,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.status = 1 THEN td.HOUR END) AS requested_days,
    SUM(CASE WHEN t.status = 2 THEN td.HOUR END) AS approved_days
FROM
    pm_participant pp

    INNER JOIN timecard t ON t.user_id = pp.user_id
    INNER JOIN timecard_day td ON td.timecard_id = t.id
GROUP BY
    pp.id,
    pp.user_id,
    CONCAT(pp.last_name, ' ', pp.first_name),
    pp.pm_part_inst_id,
    pp.signature_authority_id,
    pp.max_days
```

To see how it works (if it works; bit of a guess based on what was posted) look at the data without aggregation, but split into columns:

```
SELECT
    pp.id,
    pp.user_id,
    CONCAT(pp.last_name, ' ', pp.first_name) AS NAME,
    pp.pm_part_inst_id,
    pp.signature_authority_id,
    pp.max_days,
    '<--this data will be grouped', 'that data will be split and summed-->',
    td.status,
    td.hour,
    (CASE WHEN t.status = 1 THEN td.HOUR END) AS requested_days,
    (CASE WHEN t.status = 2 THEN td.HOUR END) AS approved_days
FROM
    pm_participant pp

    INNER JOIN timecard t ON t.user_id = pp.user_id
    INNER JOIN timecard_day td ON td.timecard_id = t.id
```

You should see four columns at the end with all the hour data in, and all the other columns are the same values (I put some fixed string constants in to point to the relevant data with a description).

Grouping them will collapse the same values (to the left of the string constants) to a single row, so all that remains is to sum the last two columns (the ones where status1 or 2 is split out to separate columns). It is the CASE WHEN that splits the td data into two columns based on status

Comment: Okay, thank you for this answer. It's more pretty than my query and work fine!